# Spring & static content ( css, js)

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, static-content

I want to create simple app, that would use css and js. But I can't reach that static content... I've found some solutions, but I wasn't able to modify them for my solution :(

Would be anybody please so kind and could show some explicit solution (where to add/modify something and what exactly to add/modify) ?

my app structure in navigator:
http://i.nahraj.to/f/gNc.jpg

Content of web.xml and servlet-context.xml http://pastebin.com/fVcNZPst

I'm running my app on tomcat server.

The home.jsp page is correct, because when I rewrite it to home.html and open it via web browser, it shows correctly. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Very broad request here - suggest finding some tutorials with step-by-step, get it working then modify them as a learning tool.

Comment: good idea...if I'll find some solution, I'll write some toutorial :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in your structure:

a. You have put `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` for mapping your resources, this would map anything with uri starting with `/resources/` to locations under your webapp, in your structure that would be `src/main/webapp/resources`, you however don't have that folder.

b. If you want your files from `webapp/css`, `webapp/img`, `webapp/js` to be available either you can move them into `src/main/webapp/resources` folder and access them with say `/resources/js/test.js` uri or just put this entry into your servlet-context.xml file also - `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` - if you are interested I have provided more details [here](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2012/10/spring-mvc-static-resource-handling.html)